# Strengthening a gazebo roof support rod that was previously bent

Tags: pipe, steel, aluminum, welding

Snow fell on my gazebo while I still had the canopy on it. It bent the rods inwards and downward. I have managed to straighten them as much as I could, but I feel like they need to be strengthened where they've bent, to prevent the roof collapsing under its own weight, when I put them back on.

[image]

[image]

The idea I came up with was: I've cut pieces out of the aluminum handle of an old broom. I am sliding the aluminum piece (which has a slightly greater diameter) over the weak point and I was hoping to tighten it down with steel clamps.
[image]

[image]

However, the clamps cannot be tightened down enough, to bend the support piece tightly over the rod. I am thinking about welding the aluminum support pieces, rather than clamping them down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aluminum doesn't weld, at least not easily. If the struts are AL, you'll probably need some sort of epoxy to make that work. If the struts are some sort of steel, this will work OK, but you'd want a steel sleeve to weld on to it.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for your comment. Any alternative ideas that don't involve welding? Maybe I should just buy EMT tubes, cut to size and replace this whole thing, but my issue is getting the right diameters, as this is stackable

Comment: "stackable". Does that mean the tubes fit into one another and extend out to support the roof? If so, you're going to need exact replacement diameter so they will fit. In that case, your best bet is probably going to be to contact the original manufacturer for replacement parts (or look online for replacement parts for your make/model). You _might_ be able to cobble it together out of standard, off-the-shelf tubing, but then you've got things like those ball/pin retainers that you'll have to drill your own holes for, etc. Not going to be easy.

Comment: Yeah I think EMT is the way, cutting to size shouldn't be difficult, neither drilling the holes. My biggest concern is reducing the diameter at the end of the tube.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer your question. That's perfectly acceptable here and allows this to be closed out.

Comment: Put a piece of solid metal rod inside

Comment: How do I hold it in place?

Comment: Drill small hole through the hollow tube and into the inner rod, screw in small screw into it is the simplest. Alternate drill larger hole in inner rod which is large enough for the spring mechanism to fit inside so the rod is flush to the end, and the spring mechanism runs through the inner rod

Answer (score 0):

I had an old umbrella that I used the stems or arms and cut those "pipe" pieces longer than the tube and placed  inside. I will screw each end down and then put epoxy glue as well...

Comment: All the umbrellas that I've owned and seen so far have really a flimsy structure (which is fine as they support a very small canopy). How would that be able strengthen a load bearing tube for a terrace sized canopy, which even without snow will see rain and wind loads? Can you perhaps add a few pictures of your solution?